# How can I rotate a Container widget in 2D around a specified anchor point?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to perform a very simple 2D rotation of a Container widget (that contains a handful of other widgets.) This widget would be rotated around a single fixed point in the center, with no deformations.

I tried using the `transform` property with `Matrix4.rotationZ`, which somewhat works – but the anchor point is in the **top-left** corner, not in the **center**. Is there an easy way to specify that anchor point?

Furthermore, is there an easier way to 2D-rotate this widget that doesn't require Matrix4?

[image: desired and actual transformations]

```
var container = new Container (
  child: new Stack (
    children: [
      new Image.asset ( // background photo
        "assets/texture.jpg",
        fit: ImageFit.cover,
      ),
      new Center (
        child: new Container (
          child: new Text (
            "Lorem ipsum",
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 42.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
            )
          ),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration (
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
          transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(0.174533), // rotate -10 deg
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  width: 400.0,
  height: 200.0,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a translation (to and from the fulcrum) before and after the rotation.

You can create yourself a little widget that does this, and thus solve your other problem at the same time (hiding the Matrix4).

Answer (score 19):

You can use RotatedBox Widget to rotate any widget:

```
RotatedBox(
    quarterTurns: 3,
    child: Container(
        color:Colors.red
    ),
),
```

Comment: It is probably noteworthy to mention that you can only rotate in quarter turns, with no fractions.

Comment: Can this be animated?

Answer (score 17):

Per Ian's advice, I gave the following a try. It appears to work, at least in my limited testing.

The container is nested within a [Transform widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html). Using  `alignment` allows one to adjust the transform-origin in relative terms, i.e., in the center, the top left, etc.

```
var container = new Container (
  child: new Stack (
    children: [
      new Image.asset ( // background photo
        "assets/texture.jpg",
        fit: ImageFit.cover,
      ),
      new Center (
        child: new Transform (
          child: new Container (
            child: new Text (
              "Lorem ipsum",
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 42.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
              )
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration (
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ),
            padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),              
          ),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center, // set transform origin
          transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(0.174533), // rotate -10 deg
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  width: 400.0,
  height: 200.0,
);
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/matrix4_transform
This is a very helpful package for transformations.

Answer (score 9):

In flutter 2.2

Use Transform:

```
Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(...),
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
    child: Container(...)
```

Or set `transformAlignment` value in Container:

```
Container(
    ...
    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(...),
    transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

### For those who want to make an app like me, just using [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) and [Gesturedetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html). And remember don't use Draggable and Gesturedetector together because you only can drag and drop but you can't zooming widget :)).

Refer:
[A Deep Dive Into Transform Widgets in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-transform-widgets-in-flutter-4dc32cd575a9)

[barbswatanabe](https://gist.github.com/barbswatanabe/ebac19be6cc421dd7502c1491a73221a)

:[image]

```
             Transform.rotate(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  angle: state.listStickerModel[index].angle,
                  child: Transform(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    transform: new Matrix4.diagonal3(vector.Vector3(
                        state.listStickerModel[index].zoom,
                        state.listStickerModel[index].zoom,
                        state.listStickerModel[index].zoom)),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onScaleStart: (detail) {
                        _editPhotoBloc.add(UpdateSticker(
                          index: index,
                          offset: detail.focalPoint,
                          previousZoom: state.listStickerModel[index].zoom,
                        ));
                      },
                      onScaleUpdate: (detail) {
                        _editPhotoBloc.add(UpdateSticker(
                            index: index,
                            offset: Offset(detail.localFocalPoint.dx,
                                detail.focalPoint.dy),
                            angle: detail.rotation,
                            zoom:
                                state.listStickerModel[index].previousZoom *
                                    detail.scale));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            state.listStickerModel[index].src),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```