# AnimatedContainer Rotation gives unwanted rotation

Tags: flutter

I have been struggling with Flutter with something that in my head seems to simple. I want a container that spins when pressing a button and this should be animated. I have a container in the center of my screen. I have 2 buttons, 1 with "+" and with a "-". When I press the "+" I want the container to rotate 180 degrees in a clockwise rotation, If I press the "+" again I want it to perform another clockwise rotation of 180 degrees. When pressing "-" I want it to spin counter clockwise for 180 degrees.

Currently I have it build so that it will rotate container however the axis is on the top left point of the container instead of the center. I have tried to tackle this but nothing seems to change this behaviour and I found this issue but it's since been closed

> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27419

It's mind boggling to me that I cannot perform such a simple operation and was wondering if someone knows where I'm going wrong.

Some code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(Spinner());

class Spinner extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _SpinnerState createState() => _SpinnerState();
}

class _SpinnerState extends State<Spinner>  {
  double _angle = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(_angle),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.blue
              ),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _angle += 180 * pi / 180;
                });
              },
                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 20,
              ),
               FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
                   setState(() {
                   _angle -= 180 * pi / 180;
               });
              },
               child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

I did find this post however when using it the container instantly snaps to the new position and I want this to be animted.

> [How can I rotate a Container widget in 2D around a specified anchor point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603111/how-can-i-rotate-a-container-widget-in-2d-around-a-specified-anchor-point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to tackle this problem, instead of using the animatedContained I decided to use an Animation Controller.

my SpinnerState class now looks like this:

```
class _SpinnerState extends State<RadialMenu> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900), vsync: this);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadialAnimation(controller: controller);
  }
}
```

I then created a stateless widget which contains the animations etc.

```
class SpinnerAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  SpinnerAnimation({Key key, this.controller})
  : rotation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 180.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller,
        curve: Interval(
          0.0,
          0.75,
          curve: Curves.linear,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    super(key: key);
  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<double> rotation;
  build(context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: controller,
    builder: (context, builder) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: _open,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green),
          FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: _close,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          Transform.rotate(
              angle: radians(rotation.value),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('images/CRLogo.png'))),
                  )
                ],
              ))
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  _open() {
    controller.forward(from: 0);
  }

  _close() {
    controller.reverse(from: 1);
  }
}
```

This has at least solved this problem for me and I hope it helps someone else in the future.